# Bluetooth connection like wearable devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, wearables, mi

I am searching for some way that can connect to Bluetooth devices without pairing. Or at least make a connection first and then it does not need to be established all the time. Like how wearable devices work (i.e. mi band 6 or Huawei band 6). Can someone please guide me towards some helpful demo or documentation for this somewhere?
Also, I was wondering how was the security managed since my Bluetooth is always on to communicate to the wearable device. Though, turning off discoverability does not seem to create any issues in order to communicate with the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most wearables nowadays use Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), and with BLE you don't need to pair in order to exchange data - i.e. only a connection is needed. That being said, it is recommended to pair as the data exchanged between the wearable device and the phone will be encrypted, in addition to some other benefits in terms of privacy and security, Have a look at the links below that will go over connection/pairing in more detail:-

- [Should one create a bond with BLE device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862560/should-one-create-a-bond-with-a-bluetooth-le-device)
- [The Ultimate Guide to Android Bluetooth Low Energy](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/)
- [Making Android BLE work](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-4-72a0b85cb442)